# jquery change text to hyperlink through all Div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have page say

```
<div class="wrapper" id="checkLink">
    <div name="something">
       <div name="something">
          <bean:write name="" property=""/>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div name="something">
       <div name="something">
           <div name="something">
                 <bean:write name="" property=""/>
           </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want to change any text within "checkLink" div to a hyperlink if it starts with a http/https/www

The data comes from the back end and is entered by the end users... There are 90 odd fields(Out of which anyone could be a hyperlink)

Only the matching  values should appear as hyperlinks

How do I convert them into hyperlinks?

Comment: There is no text in your example, only divs.

Comment: I suspect that jQuery alone isn't going to have this functionality.  It sounds like you'd need to, for each identified "node" in your DOM, parse all of the text therein to find matching strings and split based on those strings.  Then replace the matching strings with `a` elements and re-construct the overall contents of the node from the split strings and new `a` elements.  (It also wouldn't surprise me if there's a jQuery plugin already which does exactly or very similarly this very thing.)

Comment: @Heru-Luin updated the example :)

Comment: There is still no text in your code.
Can you give an example of what it should look like in the end ?

Comment: Suppose this is the text in my page:                                                   WTC Event Bean RNAME : text 

WTC Event Details RNAME : www.google.com 

WTC PI Bean RNAME : test1 

DUCS (CSI) : test 

UQ (LB) : www.hhh.com                                                                                  
the text for UQ(LB) and WTC Event Details RNAME should come as hyperlinks on the page

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/w033ucrm/1/

```
var divs = $('#checkLink div');
$.each(divs, function(index, div){
    var target = $(div).attr('name');
   $('body').append('<a href="http://www'+target+'">'+target+'</a><br/>'); 
});
```

you could also use `$(div).replaceWith()` but with nested divs you'd only get 2 anchors